# Second screen goes black on certain website (Firefox/Chrome on Windows 8.1 on MacBook Air)

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, boot-camp, dvi, displayport

Whenever I go to http://htw-berlin.de (the only URL with this issue so far) with Firefox 38 or Chrome Canary 45, the **entire screen goes black** until I close the tab. But only **if the window is larger** than a certain size, and not the notebook screen:

http://youtu.be/aR5NLVTf0cU

My 2013 13" AirBook is connected to a Samsung SyncMaster SA200 screen (**DisplayPort > DVI**), using it as primary display at 1920x1080 @ 60Hz. The notebook screen runs at native resolution of 1440x900. My OS is **Windows 8.1 64bit with Bootcamp 5.1**.

It's the same with hardware acceleration turned off in the browsers. I updated the Intel HD graphics driver via Windows Update, but no improvement.

Comment: The youtube video does not play. Can you provide a link to the actual youtube video?

Comment: It's not a YouTube video, but a shared Google Photos link, and it works here (private window)?! Anyway, it's now an actual YouTube link.